# White Spaces behind tkinter gui python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[image]I have 1 file where its called tabs and im implementing an simple tab code. i have 3 classes that im calling into each tab. They work independently. But im having trouble with the design. White or grey spaces are appearing around each element on the user interface.

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk
from avg import AvgCode
from ssd import SSDCode
from nipc import NipcCode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TNotebook", background='white', borderwidth=0)
    style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background='white')

    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root, style="TNotebook")
    
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab1, text='Average Intensity')
    avg_code = AvgCode(tab1)

    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab2, text='Sum of Squared Differences')
    ssd_code = SSDCode(tab2)

    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab3, text='Normalized Inner-Product Coefficient')
    nipc_code = NipcCode(tab3)

    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    root.mainloop()[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CA3w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CA3w.png)
```

Ive tried changing from grid() , to pack() but nothing. Then i thought maybe its the appearence from my mac and i switched from dark mode.

Comment: I don't see any white in the image, except for some of the text and the background of a couple of buttons. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You just need to style your elements for avoiding that. Like, fgcolor , bordercolor, textstyle etc. Also, find HEX color and use that.

Comment: You need to post the code of the modules, `avg`, `ssd` and `nipc`.